# Converting a struct to a tuple slice without reflection

Tags: go

I need to convert a `struct` into a `[]Tuple`. Each tuple will represent a path to each leaf node of the struct. For example:

```
type inner struct {
  D int
}

type Example struct {
  A string
  B *inner
  C []inner
}

e := Example{
  A: "a",
  B: &inner{
    D: 0,
  },
  C: []inner{
    inner{D:0}, inner{D:1}, inner{D:2},
  },
}

func toTuple(e *Example) []Tuple {
  // this function should return:
  //  [
  //    Tuple{"A", "a"}
  //    Tuple{"B", "D", "0"}
  //    Tuple{"C", 0, "D", 0}
  //    Tuple{"C", 1, "D", 1}
  //    Tuple{"C", 2, "D", 2}
  //  ]
}
```

Is there any way to do this without having to manually specify each Tuple? I want to avoid having to do stuff like:

```
tuples = append(tuples, Tuple{"A", e.A})
...
...
for i, v := range e.C {
  tuples = append(tuples, Tuple{"C", i, "D", v.D}
}
```

because the struct could be quite large and that would lead to brittle, error prone code (for example if a new field is added to the struct).

As this is a performance sensitive application,  I'd like to avoid the use of reflection. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: If this needs to continue to work even when the strict fields change, it needs to dynamically determine the names and types of all the fields. There’s almost certainly no way to do that without reflection or something equivalently expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to use reflection. I know reflection gets a bad rap performance-wise, but it's worth your time to try it and benchmark it before you write it off.

Alternatively, you can use code generation - will probably still use reflection, but it would happen at codegen time to output go code that would be compiled together so the performance implication would not be at runtime.